# How to search on multiple (custom) fields using Element API

Tags: craft3, plugin-elementapi

I am using the Element API to search for entries that match a search query: either the title **OR** the excerpt should contain the query term. The entry is very simple and has these fields:

-title
-excerpt
-link

when I use this to only search in the title field it works:

```
$section_handle = ['item'];
$q = Craft::$app->request->getParam('query');

$criteria = [
   'section' => $section_handle, 
   'search' => 'title:'.$q
];
```

So I thought I just add the excerpt field like this:

```
$criteria = [
   'section' => $section_handle, 
   'search' => 'title:'.$q.' OR '.'excerpt:'.$q
];
```

but this did NOT work and I found out that it just won't search that excerpt field, this also does not work:

```
   $criteria = [
   'section' => $section_handle, 
   'search' => 'excerpt:'.$q
];
```

After some research I found out that when I use this as the 'criteria' it works:

```
$criteria = [
    'section' => $section_handle, 
    'excerpt' => "*{$q}*"
];
```

And now I wonder how to proceed. How can I either get the first example to work to search in the excerpt field, or add the OR title clause to my latest example where I am able to search in the excerpt field...

I hope this makes sense and that someone can point me in the right direction!

Thanks very much,

Wouter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your last example:

```php
$criteria = [
    'section' => $section_handle, 
    'excerpt' => "*{$q}*"
];
```

You are making a [fuzzy search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) by surrounding your keyword(s) with `*` ([see docs for syntaxes](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/searching.html#supported-syntaxes)) and I wonder if that's why you are seeing results (I'd need to see the keywords/entry).

However, if that works, then this should work for you:

```php
'criteria' => [
    'section' => $section_handle,
    'search' => ($q ? 'title:' . $q . ' OR '.'excerpt:*'. $q . '*' : null),
],
```

Alternatively, make everything fuzzy (not *as* precise):

```php
'criteria' => [
    'section' => $section_handle,
    'search' => ($q ? 'title:*' . $q . '* OR '.'excerpt:*'. $q . '*' : null),
],
```

One final thought, if your section has three fields, if you only check *Use this field’s values as search keywords* on your Settings → Fields → excerpt field then you can search on both title + excerpt simply by doing:

```php
'criteria' => [
    'section' => $section_handle,
    'search' => ($q ?? null),
],
```

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your answer. It did help as in I understand it a bit better, and I finally got it to work!

The solution seems to be this:

**check the excerpts field 'use this field's values as search keywords'**

But then I had to recreate the entries and only then the searching worked!

I am very happy I got it to work now, thanks again Oli!!!

Comment: Oh! I see :) To re-index your entries, you can run `./craft resave/entries --update-search-index` ([docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/console-commands.html#resave-entries)) rather than having to recreate them.